# TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm learning React and I'm trying to do a little project. This project is showing a list of users of a `jsonPlaceholder` and wanted to make it to edit the fields.

I have a div that loads the list, another hidden div with editable fields and a button that when clicked the list div is hidden and the other one appears.

When I click the button it gives the following error:

> "TypeError: Can not read property 'handleClick' of undefined"

Can anyone help?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      displayList: 'block',
      displayForm: 'none'
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response  => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({users: json}));
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({displayList: 'none', displayForm: 'block'})
  }

  render(){
    const list = this.state.displayList;
    const form = this.state.displayForm;

    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(function(item){
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <br></br>

              <div style={{display: list}}>
                <h2>{item.name} </h2>
                <p>Email: {item.email} </p>
                <p>Address: </p>
                <ul>
                  <li>Street: {item.address.street} </li>
                  <li>Suite: {item.address.suite} </li>
                  <li>City: {item.address.city} </li>
                  <li>ZipCode: {item.address.zipcode} </li>
                </ul>
                <p>Phone: {item.phone} </ p>
              </div>

              <div style={{display: form}} >
                <div>
                  <h2>{item.name} </h2>
                  <p>Email: <input value = {item.email} className="form-control" onChange=""/> </p>
                  <p>Address: </p>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Street: <input value = {item.address.street} className="form-control" /> </li>
                    <li>Suite: <input value = {item.address.suite} className="form-control" /> </li>
                    <li>City: <input value = {item.address.city} className="form-control" /> </li>
                    <li>ZipCode: <input value = {item.address.zipcode} className="form-control" /> </li>
                  </ul>
                  <p>Phone: <input value = {item.phone} className="form-control" /> </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}> Edit </button>
              <hr></hr>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the callback in the map method `this.state.users.map` is not bound. You need to turn that into an arrow function. like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      displayList: 'block',
      displayForm: 'none'
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers(id){
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response  => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({users: json}));
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({displayList: 'none', displayForm: 'block'})
  }

  render(){
    const list = this.state.displayList;
    const form = this.state.displayForm;

    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map((item => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <br></br>

              <div style={{display: list}}>
                <h2>{item.name} </h2>
                <p>Email: {item.email} </p>
                <p>Address: </p>
                <ul>
                  <li>Street: {item.address.street} </li>
                  <li>Suite: {item.address.suite} </li>
                  <li>City: {item.address.city} </li>
                  <li>ZipCode: {item.address.zipcode} </li>
                </ul>
                <p>Phone: {item.phone} </ p>
              </div>

              <div style={{display: form}} >
                <div>
                  <h2>{item.name} </h2>
                  <p>Email: <input value = {item.email} className="form-control" onChange=""/> </p>
                  <p>Address: </p>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Street: <input value = {item.address.street} className="form-control" /> </li>
                    <li>Suite: <input value = {item.address.suite} className="form-control" /> </li>
                    <li>City: <input value = {item.address.city} className="form-control" /> </li>
                    <li>ZipCode: <input value = {item.address.zipcode} className="form-control" /> </li>
                  </ul>
                  <p>Phone: <input value = {item.phone} className="form-control" /> </p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Edit </button>
              <hr></hr>
            </div>
          )
        }))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: you know how I can do it but just on the user that i click? passing the id of user to handleClick, for example

Comment: yes, you need to pass an unexecuted function, so go like this `<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(user)}> Edit </button>` and then the user will be passed as a parameter to the method. This computes the effect of `handleClick(user)` but doesn't execute until click

Comment: yes I did it too ahah I will try to find the rest of code inside hadleClick to change just one

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `this.handleClick` is referenced inside a callback defined as a regular `function` that is passed to a `map`. Regular function have [their own values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Simple_call) of `this` which is not the component.

In order to [retain the value of this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions) you call pass the callback to the map as an arrow function:

```
render () {
    /* ... */
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map((item) => { /* ... */ })}
      </ul>
    )
}
```

Alternatively you can explicitly pass `this` value as a second argument to the `map`

```
render () {
    /* ... */
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(function(item) { /* ... */ }, this)}
      </ul>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the method to the object.

Either:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({displayList: 'none', displayForm: 'block'})
}
```

or:

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> Edit </button>
```

Otherwise it loses the context.

Comment: It doesn't work to and appers one more error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined